# How to set facet method in SolrJ?

Tags: solr, solrj, faceted-search, facet

How to set `facet.method=enum` in SolrJ SolrQuery? I am looking for something like  `solrQuery.setFacetMethod(SOLR_FACET_METHOD.enum)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you will need to use the generic setParam method since it is not exposed directly.

```
solrQuery.setParam(FacetParams.FACET_METHOD, FacetParams.FACET_METHOD_enum)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Instead of my cooked-up enum SOLR_FACET_METHOD, we just need to use `solrQuery.setParam("facet.method", "enum")` :)

Comment: You can use the constant built into the SolrJ library. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Awesome! That's better! Actually even better is `solrQuery.setParam(FacetParams.FACET_METHOD, FacetParams.FACET_METHOD_enum)` :-)